# 500 Server Error after migration from VTiger CRM 5.4 to 6.0

Tags: php, vtiger

I recently used the Migration system to upgrade from 5.4 to 6.0

Now when I login I cannot access the Contacts tab, the Sales Order tab, nor the Invoice tab (I received `500 Internal Server` errors).

I looked at my **error_log** and found this:

> [22-Jan-2015 23:41:51] PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function FetchRow() on a non-object in /home2/swanhang/public_html/Swan_Hangers/CRM/include/database/PearDatabase.php on line 532

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Found the issue in PearDatabase.php, just had to check for if $result was object. Here is code solution starting on line 527:

```
 if (is_object($result)) { 
     $arr = $result->FetchRow();
      if(is_array($arr)) 
           $arr = array_map('to_html', $arr); 
      return $this->change_key_case($arr); 
}
```

Always backup php file BEFORE you make changes.